# Javascript array out of bounds functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, xss

in javascript when an index is out of the bounds of the array, it gets extended with undefineds.

Are there any function calls happening behind the scenes?

For example:

```
var w = []
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    w[(i << 4) + 15] = i
}
```

I am trying some prototype poisoning exercises and I noticed an array used with indexes outside its bounds, so I am hoping to modify functions related to this if it is possible.

Comment: Can you please share your code with array and with function?

Comment: Yes, JS' arrays get extended (length property is updated) when you write to indices `>= length`. That's some magic in the engine you can't tap into. You can emulate that behaviour with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your answer. I need to prepare the injection js code inside a closure, before it is loaded. I expect this can only be done with some smart prototype manipulation, however, apart from arrays,  the closure only contains primitives.

I also removed the mistake in the code example, i just typed some random things without thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const arr = new Proxy([], {
    get(target, property) {
        return target[property];
    },
    set(target, property, value) {
        // do your work here ... for example: print some values:
        console.log('oldValue=', target[property]);
        console.log('newValue=', value);
        console.log('index=', property);

        // set the new value - default behaviour
        target[property] = value;

        // Return true if successful. In strict mode, returning false will throw a TypeError exception.
        return true;
    },
});

arr[3] = 'https://sidanmor.com/';
```

Comment: This makes sense, I did not know about proxy before. However, I do not have access to the array. Is there a way to modify the prototype into using a proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by "no access"? what is missing?

Comment: I am trying to inject js code in a closure that contains an array that makes use of out of bound indexes, this was my only lead

Comment: @MisterBabu see my other answer, I think it can help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Array.prototype` like this:

NOTE the limits in the for loop!

```js
for (let i = -1000; i < 1000; i++) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, i, {
        get() {
            if (this[`_${i}`] === undefined) return 'No value'; // or throw new Error('No value');
            return this[`_${i}`];
        },
        set(v) {
            return this[`_${i}`] = v;
        },
    });
}

const arr = [];

console.log(arr[1]); // No value
arr[1] = 'I have a value'; // set value
console.log(arr[1]); // get the value 'I have a value'
console.log(arr[-1]); // No value
console.log(arr[-100]); // No value
console.log(arr[0]); // No value
console.log(arr[100]); // No value
console.log(arr[10000]); // undefined (because of the limits are -1000 to 1000)
```